# how to import kotlin.js using @JsModule

Tags: javascript, kotlin

Kotlin2Js generates two files: kotlin.js with all the necessary functions and a script that was translated from kotlin, for example "script.js"
I want to import the kotlin.js file into the "script.js" using @JsModule annotation, so as not to connect them separately.

```
@JsModule("kotlin")
external object kotlin
```

how to do it? this example does not give any results

Comment: all I've come up with is it concatenate script after build, using gradle. still waiting for proposals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is already given, its  [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/import-kotlin-js-file-using-jsmodule-annotation/6360)